# Delete all emps whose hiredate is greater than their manager

Tags: oracle

I have written

```
DELETE FROM emp
WHERE
    hiredate < (
        SELECT
            m.hiredate
        FROM
            emp e,
            emp m
        WHERE
            e.mgr = m.empno
    )
```

But this is showing only 3 rows are deleted
Note: I took demosql table which has emptable,dept, salgrade and bonus table. Pls help me out of this question.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You made these mistakes in your query:

- used `<` instead of `>` - I give you the benefit of doubt that it was
  a typo.
- There is no relation between the outer query and subquery, so even after you fixed the above point, it will still
  end up deleting all the employees whose hiredate is > all of the
  manager's hiredate.
- using old implicit join syntax (a,b) instead of ANSI standard `JOIN` syntax

Your query to *Delete all emps whose hiredate is greater than their manager*
should look more like

```
DELETE FROM emp e1 
WHERE  hiredate > (SELECT m.hiredate 
                   FROM   emp e2 
                          JOIN emp m 
                            ON e2.mgr = m.empno 
                               AND e2.empno = e1.empno);
```

To verify that this worked correctly, use this query before and after running the delete.

```
SELECT
    m.hiredate,
    e.hiredate
FROM
    emp e
    JOIN emp m ON e.mgr = m.empno
WHERE
    e.hiredate > m.hiredate;
```

To understand clearly how these things work, read a bit about correlated sub-queries and joins.